# How to define correct action parameter on forms?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Right now I have those.

```
user_add.blade.php
<form method="post" id="customForm" action="admin/user_add">
    ...
</form>

routes.php
Route::post('admin/user_add', 'admin@user_add');

admin.php
public function action_user_add()
{
   print_r(Input::get());
}
```

How should I give the correct action path? Like; `admin/user_add` or something like `{{ Base_path }}admin/user_add`? I don't want issues when I move into production server. (e.g using subfolders etc.)

Also, is my approach correct or are there better ways?

Ps. Should I use Form methods? Like `<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="small">` to `Form:text("username", "", "small");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" id="customForm" action="{{ URL::to_action('admin@user_add') }}">
```

Whether you want to use the form helpers or not, is really your choice. They make some things simpler, for example declaring the target URL, but they're a little cumbersome for writing additional HTML like you did (adding an `id` attribute to the form).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I also have one more question. The project is medium sized and there will be over 50 calls to functions. If I write them inside Route.php, things will look really messy. Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: What kind of functions? Routing code belongs to route.php, other modifications to the system can be placed in start.php. And you can, of course, split up your logic into multiple different files, which you'd then include from start.php.